# How to set HTML AccessKey using extJS

Tags: html, extjs

Hopefully everyone knows the benefit of setting the HTML accesskey property on input-fields and buttons (and various others): It makes the page easy to navigate by enabeling shortcuts (in IE by pressing 'Alt' and the accesskey).

My problem is now that I have been asked to look into extJS for building our forms (and web stuff en general) as this is delivered with our IceBreak server.

I've been able to build a form and at first I figured that I must be able to set the accesskey the same way as all the other properties... but that does not seem to be working =0/

I can see in [How to implement accesskey on ExtJs tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038658/how-to-implement-accesskey-on-extjs-tabs) and http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22812-AccessKeys-(Global-keymap) that it is possible to make something similar to accesskeys, but they seem a lot like work-arounds to me.

I just need for Alt and 0-9 or a-z to focus/active the elements. Nothing more fancy than that.

Is there a SIMPLE way of getting extJS to set the accesskey? (preferably on the html-element)

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest using the KeyMap component, but I see that the forum links already do that.  I have used the keymap object before to create keyboard shortcuts in the past.  We replicated the keyboard shortcuts that existed in the thick-client legacy application we were replacing.

If you follow the guidelines in the links you posted, that should get you to where you are going.  Following this method is what you'll need to do.

Comment: It just seems like a lot of 'work' (lines of code) to write (and subsequently maintain) to get the same effect as setting the accesskey parameter for the HTML tag, which is why I would very much like to find a 'ligth-weight' method of doing this.

Comment: The configurations can be as lightweight as you want them to be.  The KeyMap is a robust interface to the underlying HTML elements. Remember that this is in fact one of the advantages of using an AJAX framework such as ExtJS.  
Also note that the implementation of the handlers (JScript) do not necessarily have to be inside the KeyMap or KeyNav implementations.